# Drifting Maxwellian distribution for energy

Tags: statistical-mechanics, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory

Assume I have a drifting Maxwellian distribution with velocity $\vec{a}$, say, in the x-direction, so something like

$$
f(\vec{v}) = n\left(\frac{m}{2\pi k_{B}T}\right)^{3/2}e^{-\frac{m[(v_{x}-a)^{2}+v_{y}^{2}+v_{z}^{2}]}{2k_{B}T}}
$$

I would like to obtain a similar distribution, but explicitly for the energy $E = \frac{m(v_{x}^{2}+v_{y}^{2}+v_{z}^{2})}{2}$. How do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you simply want to write this in terms of $E$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Should have made this clearer, sorry about that.

Comment: Ok, what is your energy then? $m(v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2)/2$? Because the way I see it, just define the drifting energy $E=m((v_x-a)^2+v_y^2+v_z^2)/2$ and then you're done.

Comment: I need it related to the energy $\frac{m(v_{x}^{2}+v_{y}^{2}+v_{z}^{2})}{2}$ as I'll have to later use this $f(E)$ distribution to calculate some integrals. I don't think I can really go into details about that, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [second theorem of König](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28kinetics%29) states that the kinetic energy in a reference frame $E_c$ is related to the kinetic energy relatively to the center of mass $E^*_c$ in the following way:
$$E_c=E_c^*+\frac12Mv_G^2,$$
where $v_G$ is the velocity of the center of mass in the reference frame and $M$ is the total mass.

To answer your question, remark that the energy is proportionnal to $\vec v^2$ in spherical coordinates and that you should consider only a finite volume $V$ containing $nV$ particles. Perform a standard  change of coordinates and  shift energies by $nV\frac12ma^2$ to get the required distribution:
$$f(E)=\frac {2n} {\sqrt \pi(k_{\rm B}T)^{3/2}} \sqrt{E}\;\exp\left(-\frac{E-\frac12nVma^2}{k_{\rm B}T}\right).$$

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I haven't tried yet to derive this, but it seems strange to me that the term proportional to $a^{2}$ has a negative sign (well, positive if considering the negative sign in front of the fraction).

Comment: $E$ is the energy in the observer reference frame and $E-\frac12nmVa^2$ is the energy $E^*$ in the frame of the center of mass. According to Koenig's second theorem, $E^*<E$. Now keep in mind that $a^2\ll\frac{k_{\rm B}T}m$ and that this factor is thus very small compared to $E$ in the relevant domain of energy values.

Comment: I don't agree with the assumption that $a^{2} \ll \frac{k_{B}T}{m}$: at the sheath entrance near a solid walls, ions are accelerated to the sound speed $\sqrt{\frac{k_{B}T_{e}}{m_{i}}}$ (if we assume $T_{i} \simeq 0$). If you assume that the ions are then distributed as a drifting Maxwellian with $a = \sqrt{\frac{k_{B}T_{e}}{m_{i}}}$, your disequality doensn't hold.

Comment: Well, if ions are accelerated, then the gas is not at equilibrium and there is no Maxwell distribution at all, whatever the reference frame.